# why is CreateProcessWithTokenW failing with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, createprocessasuser

I have a call to CreateProcessWithTokenW that is failing with access denied.  Any ideas how to debug this?

The call to CreateProcessWithTokenW is here: https://github.com/fschwiet/PShochu/blob/master/PShochu/PInvoke/NetWrappers/ProcessUtil.cs

For now I'm using a access token for the current process, eventually I'll use a token from another user.  For now then I'm using https://github.com/fschwiet/PShochu/blob/master/PShochu/PInvoke/NetWrappers/AccessToken.cs to get the access token.

If you want to debug, pull down the sourcecode and run build_and_test.ps1.  The error stack is:

```
1) Test Error : PShochu.Tests.can_run_remote_interactive_tasks, given a psake script which writes the current process id to output, when that script is invoked interactively, then the script succeeds
   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Access is denied
   at PShochu.PInvoke.NetWrappers.ProcessUtil.CreateProcessWithToken(IntPtr userPrincipalToken, String applicationName,
String applicationCommand, Boolean dontCreateWindow, Boolean createWithProfile, StreamReader& consoleOutput, StreamReader& errorOutput) in c:\src\PShochu\PShochu\PInvoke\NetWrappers\ProcessUtil.cs:line 52
   at PShochu.ProcessHandling.RunNoninteractiveConsoleProcessForStreams2(String command, String commandArguments, String& newLine) in c:\src\PShochu\PShochu\ProcessHandling.cs:line 36
   at PShochu.ProcessHandling.RunNoninteractiveConsoleProcess(String command, String commandArguments) in c:\src\PShochu\PShochu\ProcessHandling.cs:line 20
   at PShochu.Tests.can_run_remote_interactive_tasks.<>c__DisplayClass16.<>c__DisplayClass18.<Specify>b__2() in c:\src\PShochu\PShochu.Tests\can_run_remote_interactive_tasks.cs:line 27
   at NJasmine.Core.Execution.DescribeState.<>c__DisplayClass7`1.<visitBeforeEach>b__3() in c:\src\NJasmine\NJasmine\Core\Execution\DescribeState.cs:line 62
```

Later update:  I saw in some docs that additional privileges are needed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I am having trouble getting tests to verify I have these individual securities (they are set in secpol.msc pre-reboot)

```
SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME  "Replace a process level token"
SE_TCB_NAME "Act as part of the operatin system"
SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME  "Adjust memory quotas for a process"
```

These tests keep telling me I don't have the permissions I've set in the UI, https://github.com/fschwiet/PShochu/blob/master/PShochu.Tests/verify_privileges.cs

Comment: no takes?  Yeah, I didn't want to touch it either. :P

Comment: What OS is it?  You could try running Process Monitor on it and seeing if it's something related to file or registry access (seems unlikely considering it's the same user).

Comment: Windows 7.  I'm not sure how I would see it in process explorer as, as I understand the error, the process isn't being started.

Comment: In regards to the privileges, even if you "enable" them in the UI you still have to explicitly enable them via AdjustTokenPrivileges.  I don't recall doing that in my code, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Through trial and error I figured out that the token you pass to CreateProcessWithTokenW() needs the following access flags (at least on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit):

- TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY
- TOKEN_DUPLICATE
- TOKEN_QUERY
- **TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT**
- **TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID**

The last two in bold are very helpfully not mentioned at all in the documentation for CreateProcessWithTokenW().

**EDIT**: The following code works fine for me (when running elevated):

```
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
if(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken))
{
    HANDLE hDuplicate = NULL;
    if(DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hDuplicate))
    {
        TCHAR szCommandLine[MAX_PATH];
        _tcscpy_s(szCommandLine, MAX_PATH, _T("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"));
        STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
        ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
        StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;
        ZeroMemory(&ProcessInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
        if(CreateProcessWithTokenW(hDuplicate, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, NULL, szCommandLine, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInformation))
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
            ProcessInformation.hThread = NULL;
            CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
            ProcessInformation.hProcess = NULL;
        }
        CloseHandle(hDuplicate);
        hToken = hDuplicate;
    }
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    hToken = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, very nice I look forward tonight when I can give this a try to verify.

Comment: hmm, that may have been a problem but not the last one.  I'm seeing the same error

Comment: Is your application running elevated?

Comment: I'm running in a test runner, need to split it out to see if thats the problem.  Thanks for the code, I will try working my way back from there.

Comment: Wouldn't `GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS` be sufficient for `DuplicateTokenEx`?

Comment: This SO answer made it into my video on [Microsoft Windows Security Objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmteqkbBfAY).  I ended up going in a completely different and very original direction for starting processes with other access tokens (CreateProcess() + NtSetInformationProcess()).